Incorrect Data Retrieval from Desired Registers Despite Correct Slave ID
Environment:

On: Raspberry Pi 4B
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 Jammy
libmodbus version: 3.1.10
RS485 Pi 2.0 USB UART
Modbus device is connected to: /dev/ttyUSB0 port.
Slave device ID: 33
Registers: 30001, 30002, 30003, 30004.
Due to having the slave device: Polling is necessary to read data.

Explanation:

The code aims to establish a connection to a specific Modbus device and read data from specific registers. Below is an exact connection example taken from Windows with the application poll.

The output of the code is the debug output received after establishing the connection and reading certain registers.
However, instead of the expected data, unexpected results were obtained (see the output section below).


C++ Code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <modbus.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    // The ID of the device being queried
    const int REMOTE_ID = 33;
    modbus_t *ctx;
    uint16_t tab_reg[4];

    // Creating a Modbus connection
    ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600, 'O', 8, 1);
    modbus_set_slave(ctx, 33);  // Setting the Slave ID
    modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode(ctx, MODBUS_RTU_RS485);
    modbus_rtu_set_rts(ctx, MODBUS_RTU_RTS_UP);
    modbus_rtu_set_rts_delay(ctx, 3);
    modbus_set_debug(ctx, 1);  // Enabling debugging
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create the libmodbus context\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Establishing the connection
    if (modbus_connect(ctx) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
        modbus_free(ctx);
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Reading the registers
    int rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 0, 3, tab_reg);
    if (rc == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
        std::cout << "Reading register error";
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Printing the read data
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tab_reg) / sizeof(tab_reg[0]); i++) {
        printf("reg[%d]=%d (0x%X)\n", i, tab_reg[i], tab_reg[i]);
    }
    
    // Closing the connection and freeing memory
    modbus_close(ctx);
    modbus_free(ctx);
}

Debug Output:
Opening /dev/ttyUSB0 at 9600 bauds (O, 8, 1)
[21][03][00][00][00][03][02][AB]
Sending request using RTS signal
Waiting for a confirmation...
<21><03><06><00><00><00><00><00><21><78><AC>
reg[0]=0 (0x0)
reg[1]=0 (0x0)
reg[2]=33 (0x21)
reg[3]=0 (0x0)

Further Information: 

Normally, we would set the starting value as 30001 here:
int rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 30001, 3, tab_reg);
However, an "Invalid CRC" error occurred.
According to a fellow libmodbus user:


Welcome to the wonderful world of Modbus. "30000" just means "registers," and 20000 and 40000 just mean "input registers" and "coils."
It's kind of like "modbus_operation(3000x)" will automatically do a "read_registers(x)," and "modbus_operation(4000x)" will automatically do a "read_holding_registers(x)."
libmodbus doesn't support the 30000 style, just the "full" style.


Therefore, I started with 0 instead of 30001.

Tried these two changes already:
int rc=modbus_read_input_registers(ctx,0,3,tab_reg);
    if(rc==-1){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",modbus_strerror(errno));
        std::cout<<"Reading register error";
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(tab_reg)/sizeof(tab_reg[0]);i++){
                    printf("reg[%d]=%d (0x%X)\n",i,tab_reg[i],tab_reg[i]);
                    
    }

int rc=modbus_read_input_registers(ctx,0,4,tab_reg);
    if(rc==-1){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",modbus_strerror(errno));
        std::cout<<"Reading register error";
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(tab_reg)/sizeof(tab_reg[0]);i++){
                    printf("reg[%d]=%d (0x%X)\n",i,tab_reg[i],tab_reg[i]);
                    
    }

Output:


You are using modbus_read_registers(ctx, 0, 3, tab_reg); this function should probably be called modbus_read_holding_registers because that is what it does (sends command 03 - "Read Holding Registers").
Per the screenshot (and the confusing Modicon Convention) what you actually want are "Input Registers" (read with command 04). These are two different sets of registers (the input registers are read-only whereas you can alter holding register values). Try modbus_read_input_registers and I believe you will get the data you expect.
Welcome to the wonderful world of Modbus indeed! (recommend the "Modbus: When 40001 Really Means 1, or 0 Really Means 1" section in this article)

Hello sir, I already tried that and faced Invalid CRC error as a coming output. And that's the request: [21][04][00][00][00][04][F6][A9]

Try modbus_read_input_registers(ctx,1,1,tab_reg). Unfortunately without information on the device you are trying to communicate with it's difficult to help further (would also be useful to know what application the "application poll" screenshots are from). It may be useful to test using a known good application (e.g. mbpoll/modpoll) just in case there is an issue with your code.

As I understand it to read exact register we have to apply -1 to actual value. For example 30001 = > modbus_read_input_registers(ctx,30001-(30000-1),1,tab_reg)
example 40097 = > modbus_read_registers(ctx,40097-(40000-1),1,tab_reg)

The addr parameter passed into libmodbus functions is inserted directly into the packets sent (so it's a PDU, or Wire, address). The Modbus spec (and many, but not all) documents use register address (which add 1 to this). The Modicon Convention (for your example) adds 30001. So the equation should be 30001-(30000+1) (register 30001 = PDU address 0). In theory the device should respond with an error (02 - "ILLEGAL DATA ADDRESS") if you use an invalid address but, no all devices do this (experimentation is often needed; some devices will only accept requests for specific blocks).
